# ISO C and signed literal constants

Tags: c, constants, literals, iso

I just started to read the ISO C 2011 standard , well the last public draft of it [[1]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) , and realized that in the C Lexical Grammer [[1]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)[458ff.] all (literal) numerical constants are unsigned.

Does that mean that the Compiler interpret a signed numerical constant (like -5.1E10 or -1)
as a call of the corresponding unary-operator ? 
e.g -1  <=> -(1) , +512 <=> +(512)

UPDATE:
My fault, "all (literal) numerical constants are unsigned" I mean "all (literal) numerical constants are non-negative"

Regard, Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All non-suffixed decimal integer literals are signed, but they can not be negative. Perhaps non-negative is what you meant by "unsigned", but I think it's important to make a distinction -- they are not of an `unsigned int` type.

Once you've got a positive literal, the unary operator is applied. This is why `INT_MIN` is often defined as:

```
#define INT_MIN     (-2147483647 - 1)
```

Because you can't represent 2147483648 with a `signed int` on this platform.

Comment: No, not all literals are signed, you probably mean "all decimal literals without `U` suffix are signed". Octal and hexadecimal literals can be unsigned, even without an `U` suffix.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your interpretation is correct, all number literals don't include a sign, an eventual sign is the unary operator applied to it.

The type of a literal is chosen in such a way that the value of the literal is representable within that type, so effectively valid number literals always represent a positive value.

Answer (score 2):

> all (literal) numerical constants are unsigned.

This is wrong, actually only non-prefixed decimal integer literals are signed. The other integer literals are unsigned or signed.

> Does that mean that the Compiler interpret a signed numerical constant (like -5.1E10 or -1) as a call of the corresponding unary-operator ? e.g -1 <=> -(1) , +512 <=> +(512)

If you apply `-` to an unsigned literal, its result is (usually) still unsigned.
For example:

```
-1U         // unsigned quantity
-0xFFFFFFFF // unsigned quantity (assuming 32-bit int)
```

The signed result is converted to unsigned through the rules of C integer conversion.