# How is the following code giving the output as -99?

Tags: c

Given below is a C code snippet with `str` initialized to "face":

```
char *str = "face";
printf("%d\n", -2[str]);
```

Comment: What else could it print?  There’s a duplicate about why “`a[i] == i[a]`".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I could imagine a horrible explanation (involving your fact)  for `-(2[str])` but not for the shown code...

Comment: @Yunnosch: rethink your parsing.  There are no negative literal numbers prefixed with a `-` sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we need to parse the expression in question: We have two operators in `-2[str]` - a subscript operator `[]` and a unary minus operator `-`. Subscript operator has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than unary minus, so `printf` prints a negation of `2[str]`*.

There are many Q&As explaining that `2[str]` is the same as `str[2]`, so I am not going to repeat the explanation; you can read about it [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/335858).

Finally, the value of `str[2]` is `'c'`, which represents code of `99` on your system. Negation is applied to that value, so that is how `-99` gets printed.

* Note that `-` is not part of an integer constant, because [in C integer constants do not include sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17899318/335858).

Comment: Sigh. I guess reputation attracts more reputation. And of course nice links. Could you add one to something on `-2` not being an integer literal?

Comment: @Yunnosch Sure - I added a link to SO Q&A. Johnathan added a link to the standard explaining the same point. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: My pleasure, I got something cool for my dupe library out of it. (And thanks for not taking offense at my rep-whining...)

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question is:

```
char *str = "face";
printf("%d\n", -2[str]);
```

Let's be clear: this is horrid, and anyone writing that code should be made to rewrite it.

There are two parts to the confusion when approaching this:

1. [Why is `a[i] == i[a]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)
2. How is `-2[str]` evaluated?

The linked question covers (1) extensively.  Read it.

To address the second part, consider an alternative program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "XYZface";
    char *str = &data[3];
    printf("[%s] %d %d %d (%c)\n", str, -2[str], -(2[str]), (-2)[str], (-2)[str]);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
[face] -99 -99 89 (Y)
```

Why?  The `-2[str]` notation is equivalent to `-str[2]` (you have read the linked Q&A, haven't you?) and not `str[-2]`, because there are no negative literal numbers.

Read [C11 §6.4.4.1 Integer constants](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1): there are no minus signs in there.  When you write `-2`, you have a unary minus operator and a literal `2`.  Mostly, that's the same as negative two, but not when mixed with a higher priority operator such as subscripting.  The [§6.5.2 Postfix operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2) such as subscripting have higher priority than the [§6.5.3 Unary operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3) such as negation.

Let's also be clear: there is no undefined behaviour in the question's code (or mine, I trust).  Technically, the value for letter `'c'` (`+99`) is implementation-defined, but there are few extant systems where the integer value of `'c'` is not 99 (but see [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for a code set where the answer would be different).

Answer (score 3):

Lets dissect:

```
-2[str]
```

is

```
-(2[str])
```

because of operator precedence. Note that the `-2` is not directly an integer literal; `2` is and it can receive the unary operator `-`, but before that happens, the `[]` operator is applied.
Next step is

```
-(str[2])
```

Because (a well known if curious fact) `a[i]==i[a]`.

```
-('c')
```

Because of the format string `%d`, this is seen as a negative `int`, with the absolute value of the ASCII value of `'c'`.

```
-(99)
-99
```

*(This is of course a compilation of know-how by several commenters: 
Jonathan Leffler, StoryTeller and a little by myself.)*

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments the code is working like this:

`-(2[str])` => `-(*(2 + str))` => `-str[2]`

As `str[2]` is `'c'`, whose `ASCII` value is `99`. So the output is `-99`.

Thanks, storyteller for clearing this out.